# TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable using pandas apply() with custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tying to use Pandas dataframe Apply() function for updating all rows with a function. Result is a TypeError

```
----> 1 df_usnews['AvgMathSAT_IQR'].apply(interquartile(df_usnews))

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2235             values = lib.map_infer(values, boxer)
   2236 
-> 2237         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2238         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
   2239             from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:63043)()

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

def interquartile(df):
        return pd.to_numeric(df.ThirdQuartileMathSAT) - pd.to_numeric(df.FirstQuartileMathSAT)


q75_upper = np.percentile(df_usnews.AvgMathSAT, q=75, interpolation='higher', axis=0)
q25_lower = np.percentile(df_usnews.AvgMathSAT, q=25, interpolation='lower', axis=0)
interquartile = q75_upper - q25_lower
df_usnews['AvgMathSAT_IQR'] = 0
df_usnews['AvgMathSAT_IQR'].apply(interquartile(df_usnews))
```

Comment: The output of `interquartile(df)` is a `Series` object.You are trying to apply a Series as a function. Hence the error.

Comment: Can you share same input data, including desired output, so we can show you how `apply` works?

Comment: Sample data : -1
 -1
138
26
38
144
-1
22
116
47
-1
2
-1
156
156
81
-1
Name: AvgMathSAT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing your code, since `interquartile` operates on the DataFrame, `apply` must as well. You'd need to do

```
df_usnews['AvgMathSAT_IQR'] = df_usnews.apply(interquartile)
```

Note that when passing the function to `apply`, it is passed without arguments (i.e., it is not called).

Thankfully, `pd.to_numeric` is vectorised, so you don't need to apply the function here.

```
df_usnews['AvgMathSAT_IQR'] = interquartile(df_usnews)
```

Or,

```
df_usnews['AvgMathSAT_IQR'] = df_usnews.pipe(interquartile)
```

Is going to be a lot faster.